# Put three figures in a row with subcaption in IEEE format

Tags: subfloats

i am using ieee 2 column format , here's is my code for displaying 3 figures in row in 2 column by cols span

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
 \begin{minipage}[t]{.31\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/Figure1.png}%
        \caption{abc} \label{Fig1:a}
  \end{minipage}\hfil                 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{{Figures/Figure2.png}}
\caption{abc} \label{Fig2:b}
\end{minipage}\hfil
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{{Figures/Figure3.png}}
\caption{abc} \label{Fig3:c}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

now , i want to add 1 caption for 3 figures and i wanted to make them subfigures a, b,c , like this image  [image]i tried this code

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
  %\setkeys{Gin}{width=.49\linewidth} 
%\begin{minipage}[t]{1\columnwidth}
 \begin{minipage}[t]{.31\linewidth}
\subfloat[abc] {\label{Fig1:a} \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/Figure1gasa.png}}\hfill


\subfloat[abc] {\label{Fig2:b} \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/Figure2b.png}}\hfill


\subfloat[abc] {\label{Fig3:c} \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/Figure3c.png}}

\caption{Gvvv} \label{Fig1:fgdd}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

but its displacing figures vertical in the center of document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While in text mode (as opposed to math mode), all-blank lines generate paragraph breaks. That's no different inside a `figure*` environment than it is outside. Corollary: If you don't want to create line breaks between the subfigures, don't provide all-blank lines in the input file.

No need to encase the `\subfloat` directives in a `minipage` environment. No need to employ the `.png` filename extensions either; LaTeX can figure it out on its own.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,demo]{IEEEtran} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{subfig}    % for \subfloat macro
\usepackage{graphicx}  % for \includegraphics macro
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\subfloat[abc]{\label{Fig1:a} \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{Figures/Figure1gasa}}%
\hfill
\subfloat[def]{\label{Fig1:b} \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{Figures/Figure2b}}%
\hfill
\subfloat[ghi]{\label{Fig1:c} \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{Figures/Figure3c}}

\caption{Gvvv} \label{Fig1:fgdd}
\end{figure*} 

\end{document}
```